# Logo protruding from navbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I can make my logo fit in the Navbar. I just put it in the . However, I want my logo to protrude a little bit from the Navbar. That is, I want 10% of my logo above the navbar and 10% of it below the navbar and the rest of the logo should be centered in the navbar.

I'm using a template that was bought online from wrapbootstrap.com and the template obvouisly uses bootstrap. Here is the code for the navbar

```html
<div class="navbar-header">
  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#custom-collapse">
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  </button>
  <img src="assets/images/logo.png" alt="Logo">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could probably use z-indexes for that and make the image just that 10% bigger. So make a class for the logo`

```
    .logo {
    z-index: 2;
    margin-top: -10px; /* You just have to play with this a little bit to get the preferred result*/
    }
    .navbar-header {
    z-index: 1; 
    }
```

and then make the logo just a bit bigger. Play a little with the width and height. 
`

Comment: One question though. This only makes the lower part of the logo protrude. How do I make the top part protrude as well. I.e. center the logo vertically in the navbar?

Comment: Great that it works! Awesome. You could use margin-top and play with that a little bit. See the altered code above for the example :) Good luck!

Comment: wow that was simple...I did something much more complicated 'position: relative; top: 50%; transform: translateY(-17%);'

Comment: I am really glad it worked out in the end! Good luck with your website! :)

Answer (score 0):

I would use relative and absolute positioning. If your navbar has a height of 50px and the logo is 70px high you can set `.navbar-header{position:relative; height:50px;}` and `.logo{position:absolute; top:-10px;}` this leaves you with 10px above and below the navbar.

Comment: doing this makes the logo dissapear

Comment: I think that's because you'd need to specify height and width properties of your logo's CSS (if you haven't already done so)